# JUnit: obj cannot be resolved

Tags: java, junit, compiler-errors, junit4

I made a small Java program using JUnit 4. I wrote two methods, one with a `@Before` annotation and one with `@Test`.
I created an object of a class `obj` but it says `obj` can't be resolved.

```
@Before
public void objectCreation() {
    Main obj = new Main(msg);
}

@Test
public void testPrintMessage() {      
   assertTrue("Expected true got false",obj.printMessage());
}
```

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: 1. Please post code, not images. 2. Learn about scope of variables in Java: https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope

Answer (score 1):

`obj` is a local variable in your `objectCreation` method. You should declare it as a member, and only initialize it in that method:

```java
public class JunitDemo {
    private static final String msg = "Hello world";
    Main obj;

    @Before
    public void objectCreation() {
        obj = new Main(msg);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPrintMessage() {      
       assertTrue("Expected true got false", obj.printMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Note that unless the `Main(String)` constructor declares that it throws a checked exception, there is no need to use `@Before` in the test. You can simply assign "obj" at declaration time: `private final Main obj = new Main(msg)`